# Zend_XmlRpc_Client underscore in hostname

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, xml-rpc, hostname

Running into a issue with Zend as it's throwing a error. I beleive it's due to the underscore in the hostname as Zend does some validation on the URL.

I have a Python client that does the same basic functionality and it works as expected.

Wanted to know if there is a workaround for PHP

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Uri_Exception' with message 'Invalid URI supplied' in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Uri/Http.php:156
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Uri.php(143): Zend_Uri_Http->__construct('http', '//local_server_f...')
#1 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Http/Client.php(270): Zend_Uri::factory('http://local_ser...')
#2 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php(266): Zend_Http_Client->setUri('http://local_ser...')
#3 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php(361): Zend_XmlRpc_Client->doRequest(Object(Zend_XmlRpc_Request))
#4 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/XmlRpc/Client/ServerProxy.php(93): Zend_XmlRpc_Client->call('system.multical...', Array)
#5 [internal function]: Zend_XmlRpc_Client_ServerProxy->__call('multicall', Array)
#6 /path/to/xmlrpc.client.php(21): Zend_XmlRpc_Client_ServerProxy->multicall(Array)
#7 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Uri/Http.php on line 156
```

PHP:

```
ini_set("include_path", "/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php");
require_once('Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php');

$server = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://local_server_foo/xmlrpc.server.php');

// Get the HTTP Client used by the XMLRPC client and Increase the HTTP timeout
$server->getHttpClient()->setConfig(array('timeout'=>30)); 

$client = $server->getProxy(); 

$request = array(
    array(
        'methodName' => 'system.listMethods', 
        'params'     => array() 
    )
);

try {
    $response = $client->system->multicall($request); 
    echo print_r($response,true);
} catch (Zend_XmlRpc_Client_HttpException $e) {
    echo 'HTTP Exception: '."\n";
    echo $e->getCode();
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (Zend_XmlRpc_Client_FaultException $e) {
    echo 'Fault Exception: '."\n";
    echo $e->getCode();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Python (this works):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import xmlrpclib

servAddr = "http://local_server_foo/xmlrpc.server.php"

client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(servAddr)

print

methods = client.system.listMethods()
for m in methods:
    print m + "\tHelp Documentation: " + client.system.methodHelp(m)
    print
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname (which links to the relevant RFC):

> The Internet standards (Request for Comments) for protocols mandate
>   that component hostname labels may contain only the ASCII letters 'a'
>   through 'z' (in a case-insensitive manner), the digits '0' through
>   '9', and the hyphen ('-'). The original specification of hostnames in
>   RFC 952, mandated that labels could not start with a digit or with a
>   hyphen, and must not end with a hyphen. However, a subsequent
>   specification (RFC 1123) permitted hostname labels to start with
>   digits. No other symbols, punctuation characters, or white space are
>   permitted.
>
> While a hostname may not contain other characters, such as the
>   underscore character (_), other DNS names may contain the
>   underscore.[3] Systems such as DomainKeys and service records use the
>   underscore as a means to assure that their special character is not
>   confused with hostnames. For example, _http._sctp.www.example.com
>   specifies a service pointer for an SCTP capable webserver host (www)
>   in the domain example.com.

Having an underscore in the hostname is invalid, and the Zend Framework validator is working correctly.

Comment: No argument there and why I still have not filed a issue. The only point I see is that the validator has extensive validation above and then at the end a final regex which is labeled as "Check input against local network name schema; last chance to pass validation". If any test at all for this than why not add the underscore for local naming schemas?

Comment: A local hostname is still not allowed, according to the RFC, to have underscores. If business requirements dictate they have one, then write a custom validator that accepts them. My regex grokking skills aren't always the best, but I think the 'last chance' validator is to check for domains like 'test.local' or 'mydevdomain' which are valid hostnames, but not tld's.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for a great write up. Is there a way to allow special characters in the validation? maybe a override function?

Comment: The Zend Framework manual has a good writeup on how to write your own custom validator: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html. Be sure to read andrei's comment (3rd from the top) about where to put it.

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked in version 1.11.9 and nobody has complained yet; maybe I should finally file a bug report. I fix/update the Zend_Validate_Hostname class for the missing underscore myself like in the following lines. It's in the `isValid()` method, depending on your version at line 621 (1.11.2) to 655 (1.11.9).

The old lines:

```
$regexLocal = '/^(([a-zA-Z0-9\x2d]{1,63}\x2e)*[a-zA-Z0-9\x2d]{1,63}){1,254}$/';
$status = @preg_match($regexLocal, $value);
```

The new lines: note the change `x5f`

```
$regexLocal = '/^(([a-zA-Z0-9\x2d\x5f]{1,63}\x2e)*[a-zA-Z0-9\x2d]{1,63}){1,254}$/';
$status = @preg_match($regexLocal, $value);
```

**UDPATE** Let's refine this:

As @Just H points out in his answer underscores are not allowed but they are still wildly used. Lets blame this is on IBM and later Microsoft with NetBIOS why underscores, although not allowed, are "used" in local host names.

As a former server engineer I have seen many Intranets in major companies and they all liberally used underscores in host names. OS/2 and Windows administrators unknowingly used them in the DNS naming scheme. That's why all browsers support it, all web servers support it.

Comment: See my posted answer for why the behavior in Zend_Validate_Hostname is correct, in this instance.

Comment: instead of modifying the pattern expression is there a way to allow special characters in the validation? maybe a override function?

Comment: @Phil Write your own validator that extends to Zend_Validate_Hostname. Add an isValid() method which calls the parent first and then add additional validation like the one above to your liking.